# Reading a text file, one chunk of n lines at a time

Tags: python, python-3.3, slice

I am new to Python and have made a questionnaire program. Is there any way to have the program display each question and its choices one at a time (the next multiple choice question doesn't show unless the previous one is answered)?

I used slicing to accomplish this, but I am wondering am I doing something that is not in good practice or has a better alternate way?

```
#opens the file with questions, and is told to read only via 'r'
with open("PythonQ.txt", "r") as f:
#reads the file line by line with 'readlines'
    variable = f.readlines()
#issue was with no slicing, it was reading letter by letter. so
#without the slicing and the split, the questions would not print per question
#the goal by slicing is to get readlines to read per question, not the entire file or first 5 words    
    for line in variable[0:6]:
#this strips the brackets and splits it by commas only, otherwise it will print both       
        question = line.split(',')
#joins elements of the list which are separated by a comma  
        print(", ".join(question))

choice1 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))

#sliced for second question. Begins at five to provide room in program between first and second question. 
for line in variable[6:12]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

choice2 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))


for line in variable[12:18]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

choice3 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))


for line in variable[18:24]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

choice4 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))


for line in variable[24:30]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

choice5 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))


for line in variable[30:36]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

choice6 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))


for line in variable[36:42]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

choice7 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))


for line in variable[42:48]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

choice8 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))


for line in variable[48:54]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

choice9 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))


for line in variable[54:60]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

choice10 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))

#add up all the numbers the user typed and assigned it variable x
x = choice1 + choice2 + choice3 + choice4 + choice5 + choice6 + choice7 + choice8 + choice9 + choice10

#there are only so high a person's score can go, depending upon if user chose mostly 1's, 2's, 3's or 4's in quiz.
if x <= 13:
    print("\n\n\nYour personality and work environment type is...\n \n\n\nRealistic: The 'Doer'\n")
#another file was created for the results. Import file. Then call the function, CategoryA.
    import Results
    Results.CategoryA()
elif x <= 22:
    print("\n\n\nYour personality and work environment type is...\n \n\n\nSocial: The Helper\n")
    import Results
    Results.CategoryB()
elif x <= 31:
    print("\n\n\nYour personality and work environment type is...\n \n\n\nEnterprising: The Persuader\n")
    import Results
    Results.CategoryC()
elif x <= 40:
    print("\n\n\nYour personality and work environment type is...\n \n\n\nConventional: The Organizer\n")
    import Results
    Results.CategorD()
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the file you're reading(PythonQ.txt)?

Comment: Seems like OP reads an entire file, consisting of a quiz of six-line chunks of multiple-choice questions indexed 1)..4): `variable = f.readlines()`

Comment: What's the point of doing `question = line.split(',')` followed immediately by `print(", ".join(question))` ? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry! I added the questions to the original post.

Comment: We didn't really need the questions, but that's ok. Could infer your file-format easily from your code.

Comment: Anyway, your issue is due to using `variable = f.readlines()`. That slurps in your entire file into one giant multiline string with no splits anywhere - instead of a sequence of separate lines, as you'd get by calling `readline()` 6 times. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't help with your question, but i wanted.
Still I want ask: you have 9 same codes, so may i offer my?

your code which is repeated:

```
for line in variable[6:12]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

choice2 = eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))
```

9 times means loop:
if we rename "choice1" to "x"

```
for i in range(1,10)
    for line in variable[6*i:6*(i+1)]:
        question = line.split(',')
        print(", ".join(question))

x+=eval(input("\nYour choice?: "))
```

I accept all criticism.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a total rewrite of your code in a more Pythonic idiom, using a generator.

Your issue was you read an entire file, consisting of a quiz of six-line chunks of multiple-choice questions + answers indexed 1)..4): `variable = f.readlines()`. `variable` is a worse choice of name than `quiz_contents`, but whatever.

And you want to separately access each 6-line chunk of multiple-choice question and answers.
Since you were using `readlines()`, to access each chunk, you then had to do that weird split on ',' followed by join with ',' (seems unnecessary?) then display it.

So don't use `variable = f.readlines()`! That slurps in your entire file into one giant multiline string with no splits anywhere - instead of a sequence of separate lines (split on newline), which is what you'd get by calling `readline()` 6 times in a row. You could `split('\n')` that on newlines, but best is to avoid ever using `readlines()` in the first place. Use `readline()` instead, 6 times per question.

So here's the Pythonic approach used in the code rewrite below:

- just read each 6-line chunk as you need it. No need for giant string buffer with contents of file
- note the use of `print (line, end='') # don't add extra newline`
- we need some sort of `get_chunk()` to return each 6-line chunk. A generator is more elegant than a function in this case. It also allows us to detect EOF and return None.
- That makes the calling code waaay more elegant, since we now just say `for chunk in get_chunk(quiz_contents)`. This for-loop will terminate when it gets None from the generator
- Minor note: `get_chunk()` actually has to read 6+4 lines for each chunk - you have 4 extra blank lines in each chunk. You can trivially remove those and add print(...).
- Inside the generator, we use a list comprehension `chunk = [buf.readline() for _ in range(n)]` instead of a for-loop. But you could use a for-loop. `_` is the customary Python name for throwaway variable (e.g. in this case we just need to count to 6, we never inspect the for-loop counter otherwise)

__

```
quiz_file = './PythonQ.txt'
num_questions = 10

def get_chunk(buf, n):
    """Read n-line chunks from filehandle. Returns sequence of n lines, or None at EOF."""

    while buf:
        chunk = [buf.readline() for _ in range(n)]

        if not any(chunk):  # detect termination at end-of-file (list of ['', '',...] )
            chunk = None

        yield chunk

    # Notes:
    # This is a generator not a function: we must use 'yield' instead of 'return' to be able to return a sequence of lines, not just one single line
    # _ is customary Python name for throwaway variable


with open(quiz_file) as quiz_contents: # Note: quiz_contents is now just a filehandle, not a huge buffer. Much nicer.

    choices = [None] * num_questions

    i = 0

    for chunk in get_chunk(quiz_contents, 6+4): # need to read 6 lines + 4 blank lines

        if not chunk:
            break    
        # Don't even need to explicitly test for end-condition 'if i >= num_questions: break'  as we just make our generator yield None when we run out of questions

        print() 
        for line in chunk:
            print (line, end='') # don't add extra newline

        choices[i] = int(input("\nYour choice (1-4)?: ")) # expecting number 1..4. Strictly you should check, and loop on bad input
        i += 1

        # Don't even need to test for end-condition as we'll just run out of questions

    score = sum(choices)
    print('Your score was', score)

    # do case-specific stuff with score... could write a function process_score(score)
```